# Easing functions in WPF animation

Tags: wpf, animation, easing-functions

Can you guys tell me is there any good, kind of a sample app where you can try all those easing functions with different parameters and see the changes?

I mean there are two actual reasons why I can't built myself one:

- I simply don't have time
- I am a damn stupid indolent guy who needs to indulge his laziness

Comment: You're right. Only because and thanks to indolent nature of humankind we do have Internet, Large Hadron Collider and big spill in Mexican Gulf...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Matthew MacDonald tells about a very good example](http://tinyurl.com/animationeasing):

in his book Windows Presentation Foundation in .Net 4

Pretty good though...

Answer (score 1):

You can preview most/all of them in Expression Blend, can't you?

Not exactly a sample app, but most of the easing functions would really depend on what you're animating, wouldn't they?  So it'd be easiest to just see them on your code in a designer environment?